# Confidence interval of amplitude and horizontal shift

Tags: r, confidence-interval, ellipse

I have a linear model with sine and cosine wave as predictor. 
Y~$\alpha$sine(...)+$\beta$cosine(...).
From the parameter estimation, I know the estimation of the coefficients are:
$\hat\alpha$ = 0.65(sd = 0.15), $\hat\beta$ =0.54 (sd=0.15). The correlation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is 0. Using bivariate normal approximation, I can plot the 0.95 confidence ellipse:

```r
p <- rmvnorm(1000, c(0.65,0.54), matrix(c(0.15^2,0,0,0.15^2),2,2))
plot(p, pch=20, xlab="sine", ylab="cosine")
ellipse(mu=colMeans(p), sigma=cov(p), alpha = .05, npoints = 250, col="red")
```

Then I wish to calculate the confidence interval for $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite your model in the form given in my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/77865/919, which incorporates $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ directly, and compute a confidence interval for it using the usual techniques.

Comment: your answer does not include calculating the confidence interval. @whuber

Comment: As I indicated, that's a standard textbook calculation--there's little more to say about it.  Your software will automatically report the confidence interval, for instance.