# How to calculate time of day of the peak of a harmonic function fit from phase offset estimate from R nls

Tags: r, regression, time-series, nls

I'm trying to calculate the time of day of a harmonic function peak using nls() in R. I've looked at the posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77543/how-do-i-get-the-amplitude-and-phase-for-sine-wave-from-lm-summary), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60994/fit-a-sinusoidal-term-to-data) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60500/how-to-find-a-good-fit-for-semi-sinusoidal-model-in-r), but have not found a method to calculate time of day from phase shift estimate. **The primary issue is that the time difference I calculate from the phase offset predicted by nls does not line up with the peak in a plot of the fit over time.**

The data in the example is temperature and soil moisture data, measured every two hours and assuming a period of one day. It is easy enough to look at a plot of the fit over time of day to find the peak for a couple of variables, but in practice this will be applied to gene expression data with several hundred dependent variables so I would like to be able to calculate the peak directly from the model coefficients.

Here is some example data

```
dat = structure(list(var1 = c(20.7, 20.8, 24.8, 14.4, 4.8, 9.2, 10.5,
10, 9.4, 0, 3.6, 2, 12.1, 30.3, 15, 16.1, 3.2, 0.8, 0.4, 1.8,
2.6, 7.1, -0.3, 6.9, 16.3, 17.7, 19.4, 15.2, 10, 3.1, 7.4, 5.3,
0.8, 2.4, 2.2, 3.1), var2 = c(0.019217503, 0.096176502, 0.097817827,
0.080266426, 0.186707777, 0.174192457, 0.11665335, 0.078521574,
0.132761232, 0.121586894, 0.127378359, 0.223445706, 0.182841069,
0.059183673, 0.071830986, 0.043269231, 0.102362205, 0.144329897,
0.225423729, 0.171156894, 0.249512671, 0.395833333, 0.384466019,
0.44241573, 0.312731768, 0.320802005, 0.25994695, 0.260050251,
0.370725034, 0.380821918, 0.4375, 0.389339513, 0.445544554, 0.512696493,
0.574927954, 0.564907275), hours.cumulative = c(0, 1.966666667,
3.95, 5.9, 7.983333333, 9.933333333, 11.93333333, 13.93333333,
15.88333333, 17.86666667, 19.9, 21.93333333, 23.86666667, 25.91666667,
27.91666667, 29.93333333, 31.88333333, 33.91666667, 35.98333333,
37.95, 39.95, 42, 43.93333333, 45.95, 47.86666667, 49.9, 51.8,
53.93333333, 55.93333333, 57.93333333, 59.91666667, 61.9, 63.9,
65.9, 67.96666667, 69.95), dateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(4L, 2L, 1L,
58L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 57L, 56L, 58L, 0L, 56L, 59L, 59L, 0L, 57L,
59L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 56L, 58L, 52L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 59L,
58L, 58L, 58L, 2L, 1L), hour = c(10L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 20L,
22L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 0L,
2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 1L, 3L,
6L, 8L), mday = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L,
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L,
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L,
26L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(-1882L, -1882L, -1882L,
-1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L,
-1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L,
-1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L,
-1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L,
-1882L), wday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), yday = c(22L, 22L, 22L,
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L,
23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L,
24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), zone = c("LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT",
"LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT",
"LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT",
"LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT",
"LMT", "LMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt",
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 22L,
25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 43L, 46L, 49L, 52L, 55L, 58L, 61L,
64L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 82L, 85L, 88L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 100L,
103L, 106L), class = "data.frame")
```

Starting estimates for nls. These were generated by an initial LM fit for what it's worth, except C, which is a guess-timate

```
r.var1 = 8.107156
phi.var1 = 0.6958509
C.var1 = 8
r.var2 = 0.194156
phi.var2 = -2.866766
C.var2 = 1
```

The models

```
mod1 = nls(var1 ~ amp * sin(2*pi*hours.cumulative/24 + phase) + C, start = list(amp = r.var1, phase = phi.var1, C = C.var1), data = dat)

mod2 = nls(var2 ~ amp * sin(2*pi*hours.cumulative/24 + phase) + C * hours.cumulative, start = list(amp = r.var2, phase = phi.var2, C = C.var2), data = dat)
```

Plots of the predictions over time show that var1 prediction peaks at 14:00 and the var2 prediction peaks at 04:00

```
#loading ggplot2 for easy date-time plotting
library("ggplot2")

mod1.df = data.frame(fit = predict(mod1), x = as.POSIXct(dat$dateTime), raw = dat$var1)
ggplot(mod1.df, aes(x = x)) +
geom_point(aes(y = raw)) +
geom_path(aes(y = fit)) +
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

mod2.df = data.frame(fit = predict(mod2), x = as.POSIXct(dat$dateTime), raw = dat$var2)
ggplot(mod2.df, aes(x = x)) +
geom_point(aes(y = raw)) +
geom_path(aes(y = fit)) +
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: model 1]
[image: model 2]

I think I understand that the phase offset can be converted to time difference (in period) as `phase/(2*pi)`,  and in hours as `phase/(2*pi)*24`. For var2 model I also extract the fractional component of phase. This gives a time difference from a reference curve of 2.7 hours for var 1, and -0.6 hours for var2.

```
time_diff.var1 = coefficients(mod1)["phase"]/(2*pi) * 24
time_diff.var2 = (coefficients(mod2)["phase"] - as.integer(coefficients(mod2)["phase"]))/(2*pi) *24
```

I first assumed these would be relative to a reference curve which starts at 0 in the data or 10:00 hours, giving estimates of 13:20 for var1 (close to the actual peak) and 17:54 for var2 (not close). I next assumed a reference curve starting at 00:00, but these estimates are no better (var1 is nowhere near at 03:18, var2 is closer at 07:54). Note I am adding six hours below to calculate the peak of the curve rather than midpoint.

```
peak_var1.1 = 10 - time_diff.var1 + 6
peak_var2.1 = 10 - time_diff.var2 + 6
peak_var1.2 = 0 - time_diff.var1 + 6
peak_var2.2 = 0 - time_diff.var2 + 6
```

What am I missing? Maybe I'm totally off-base on the time difference calculations? Or am I missing something with the reference for the phase offset?

Comment: It would help us to see a graphical exposition of the problem--and constructing one very well might help you solve it, too.

Comment: Thanks @whuber I added plots of the model fits I referred to. Is that what you are looking for or something more detailed?

Comment: I am looking for a plot that compares your *data* to your interpretation of the fit.  Only then can we assess how well the fit works and whether it is even meaningful to compare the times of their peaks.

Comment: Thanks @whuber I added the data points. I had intentionally left them out because I am interested specifically in calculating time of day relative to the phase predictions, but understand wanting to see them. Note that I added a linear effect of time in the second model to account for the increasing average. I suppose another option would be to run a linear model of lm(var ~ time) and take the residuals as the dependent variable in the nls if this effects the calculation of phase

Comment: I am unable to see what the problem is: although these curves fit the data poorly, they are about the best you will do with this particular data analysis procedure.

Comment: Right --- I'm asking specially about how to calculate time of day of the peak of the sine from the phase-offset estimates from NLS(). The values I'm getting are nowhere close to the peak shown in the plots.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a solution that will work for now/for my purposes that involves extracting TOD from the data.frame based on the max values of the prediction. I still think this is a bit of a hack because it should be possible to calculate TOD directly from the phase offset estimate, but maybe I'm off-base on that. Happy to see other solutions.

A time of day column in decimal hours is first calculated from the cumulative hours column. The model predictions are sorted, and the TOD values associated with the top three prediction values (i.e., the peak of the sine function) are averaged.

```
dat$TOD.dec = dat$hours.cumulative + 10.07
dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 24 & dat$TOD.dec <= 48] = dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 24 & dat$TOD.dec <= 48] - 24
dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 48 & dat$TOD.dec <= 72] = dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 48 & dat$TOD.dec <= 72] - 48
dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 72] = dat$TOD.dec[dat$TOD.dec > 72] - 72

dat$mod1.predict = predict(mod1)
dat$mod2.predict = predict(mod2)

dat.mod1_sort = dat[order(dat$mod1.predict, decreasing = T),]
mod1.TOD_peak = sum(dat.mod1_sort[1:3,"TOD.dec"])/3
mod1.TOD_peak
[1] 13.95889

dat.mod2_sort = dat[order(dat$mod2.predict, decreasing = T),]
mod2.TOD_peak = sum(dat.mod2_sort[1:3,"TOD.dec"])/3
mod2.TOD_peak
[1] 5.303333
```